# Trouble Filtering Sharepoint List with Caml

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml, csom

I'm trying to filter a SharePoint list so that only the items with the Management field, which holds a string, as "Yes" will show up, but whenever I get to the ctx.ExecuteQuery() statement, my program blows up. I believe my CAMLQuery is structured correctly, so I'm not sure if I'm simply using it wrong or if I'm missing something. Any help would be great! thanks! The code I currently have is posted below:

```
Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
List myList = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Company Employees");
SPClient.View view = myList.DefaultView;
CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();
qry.ViewXml = "<Query>" + "< Where >" + "<Eq>" + "< FieldRef Name='Management'/>" + "< Value Type='Text'>Yes</ Value >" + "</Eq>" + "</ Where >" + "</ Query >";
myList.GetItems(qry);
ListItemCollection listItems = myList.GetItems(qry);
ctx.Load(listItems);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: What type of column is the Management field?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question. It's just a column that holds a string. I'm just trying to test filtering with it, so I'm checking if the string inside is "Yes"

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to make sure it wasn't a Yes/No field, which would need to be queried differently from Text and Choice fields.

Comment: Ah okay! I'll edit the question so that's more clear.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. I have rolled back your edit which you can see in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45038074/revisions). This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Was not aware of the best practices for this instance, so thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be missing the `<View>` tag which would wrap around your `<Query>` tag in the CAML.

With the addition of the `<View>` root element, the correct CAML XML would be as follows:

```
qry.ViewXml = 
    "<View>"+
         "<Query>"+
            "<Where>"+
                 "<Eq>"+
                     "<FieldRef Name='Management'/>"+
                     "<Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value>"+
                 "</Eq>"+
            "</Where>"+
        "</Query>"+
   "</View>";
```

**Additional Troubleshooting**

To help troubleshoot, you can try running the same query through the JavaScript client object model.

1. Visit the SharePoint site in Internet Explorer and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to open up the developer tools.
2. On the Console tab, enter the following lines of code and execute (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) them one line at a time:

-

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Company Employees");
var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
qry.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Management\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">Yes</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
var items = list.getItems(qry);
ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){alert("success!");},function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());});
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but the ExecuteQuery still throws an error. Do you think this issue is because I'm trying to filter the List Items and not just the items shown in a specific view?

Comment: No, setting the View XML on a query is a generally a good way to get a filtered subset of items. Are you able to capture the text of the error message? A lot of different things could be going wrong, such as the internal name of the field being different, or the list being past the 5000 item list view threshold, but it's hard to pin down without more information.

Comment: The error being thrown is a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Cannot complete this action. Please try again'
So I'm not really sure how to interpret that. I researched the error and all I've found is that that specific error sometimes occurs when you delete something and do not update, but I haven't deleted anything.

Comment: I received a message from the webpage upon executing the last statement in your troubleshooting steps. The message read: "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."

Comment: That ran successfully, but it does nothing to the list.

Comment: The type is "single line of text"

Comment: Just found out that the query is correctly sorting the data, but nothing is happening because I'm not actually doing anything with the queried list!

Thanks so much for the help @Thriggle

Answer (score 1):

POST HELP SOLUTION Thanks to your help, I was able to figure out how to create a new view with the desired filtering by using the following code. The main problem was with the Caml Query--I had to remove the  and  tags and then delete a few of the lines before creating the view. Below is my working solution:

```
Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
List myList = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Company Employees");
SPClient.View view = myList.DefaultView;
CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();
qry.ViewXml =
"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Management\"/><Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value></Eq></Where>";
ViewCollection viewColl = myList.Views;
string[] viewFields = { "Title", "Promoted", "Intern", "Management" };
ViewCreationInformation creationInfo = new ViewCreationInformation();
creationInfo.Title = "Management";
creationInfo.RowLimit = 50;
creationInfo.ViewFields = viewFields;
creationInfo.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.None;
creationInfo.SetAsDefaultView = false;
creationInfo.Query = qry.ViewXml;
viewColl.Add(creationInfo);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```